# ZF2 FileUpload Collection

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I am unable to get my fileupload collection to work. This is what I've done:

> https://gist.github.com/manuakasam/1ac71daf7269616f55f0

Basically the `$request->getFiles()` contains the proper information. So the upload to PHP itself works. But once the `InputFilter` runs over the data, it all gets lost. Apprently `FileRenameUpload` does something fishy and I can't figure out what exactly. All I know is my data gets lost...

Write permissions are not the problem. I'm testing this currently on my devbox on windows via PHP 5.5 CLI

Comment: have you tried by giving absolute path. Check the folder permissions as well.

Comment: as I've mentioned, path-information and file-permissions shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I have added a answer to upload the files .It works for me. May be helpful to you

Comment: I had that problem aswell a while back. In the end I skipped the FileRenameUpload and implented my own. I was tracking down the error a litle and it seemes that in my case the temp file php creates could not be found for some reason. When clearly it was there before the FileRenameUpload executed.

Comment: @cptnk any chance you could share your implementation? =) As this pretty much seems to be the exact same issue i'm running into.

Comment: Could it be the case the filter can't handle multiple files or if it does, can't handle files in a POST array (like, how ZF2 collections work)? Just guessing here..

Comment: @sam It prob is not what your looking for. I am actually quite interested in solving the issue, too. So I can refactor it. But thats what I came up with https://gist.github.com/cptnk/eb9e2abe946bf745f298. I didnt acutally override any zf functionallity, too. But I shold've. I just hope it somewhat helps though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the Collection of **Elements**. In the past only Fieldsets were supported to be in a Collection. Maybe Element support is added later, but I'm pretty sure it's buggy and therefore not working for you in this way. I reworked your code to be using Fieldsets and I got it validated and the uploaded files properly renamed and moved. The problem was inside the CollectionInputFilter, that one doesn't seem to be correctly updated to support collection of Elements.

Probably obvious: make sure to prepare the collection before validation.

Here's my modified fork of your code: https://gist.github.com/netiul/efaf8bd4545d216fd26c

**Controller**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->isPost())
    {
        $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );

        $this->incidentForm->prepare();

        $this->incidentForm->setData($post);

        if($this->incidentForm->isValid()) {
            \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($this->incidentForm->getData());
            die();
        }
    }

    return [
        'form' => $this->incidentForm
    ];
}
```

**TheFilter (not changed, well a small change)**

```
    $singleFileFilter = new InputFilter();
    $singleFileFilter->add(
        [
            'name'     => 'attachment',
            'required' => false,
            'filters'  => [
                [
                    'name'    => 'filerenameupload',
                    'options' => [
                        'target'          => 'data/incident_attachments/', /* small change here, removed the slash in front of data to make the path relative */
                        'randomize'       => true,
                        'use_upload_name' => false,
                        'overwrite'       => false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );

    $attachedFilesFilter = new CollectionInputFilter();
    $attachedFilesFilter->setInputFilter($singleFileFilter);

    $this->add($attachedFilesFilter, 'attachedFiles');
```

**TheForm**

```
    $this->setAttribute('enctype', "multipart/form-data");

    $fileElement = new Form\Element\File('attachment');
    $fileElement->setOptions(
        [
            'label'            => 'Add Attachment',
            'label_attributes' => [
                'class' => 'control-label col-sm-3'
            ]
        ]
    );
    $fileElement->setAttributes([
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ]);

    $collectionTarget = new Form\Fieldset('uploadItem');
    $collectionTarget->add($fileElement);

    $this->add(
        [
            'name'    => 'attachedFiles',
            'type'    => 'collection',
            'options' => [
                'count'          => 3,
                'target_element' => $collectionTarget
            ]
        ]
    );
```

**Output after validation**

```
array (size=1)
  'attachedFiles' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'attachment' => 
            array (size=5)
              'name' => string '1326459.png' (length=11)
              'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
              'tmp_name' => string 'data/incident_attachments_538c30fe0fb2f' (length=39)
              'error' => int 0
              'size' => int 791802
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'attachment' => 
            array (size=5)
              'name' => string '1510364_10152488321303345_257207784_n.jpg' (length=41)
              'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
              'tmp_name' => string 'data/incident_attachments_538c30fec55c4' (length=39)
              'error' => int 0
              'size' => int 53272
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'attachment' => 
            array (size=5)
              'name' => string 'IMG_20140430_095013.jpg' (length=23)
              'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
              'tmp_name' => string 'data/incident_attachments_538c30ff4489d' (length=39)
              'error' => int 0
              'size' => int 1039118
```

Comment: Right on spot, the additional nesting of one Fieldset did the trick. Sadly making this work with Doctrine is much more complex, but for the task given this is the right answer. Congratulations and thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> The way i validated files in ZF2
>
> in composer.json

```
  "imagine/Imagine": "0.3.*",
```

> in your controller

```
use Zend\Validatior\File\Size;
use Imagine\Gd\Imagine;
use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\Point;

public function imageAction()
    {

        $id = ( int ) $this->params ()->fromRoute ( 'id', 0 );
        if (! $id) {
            return $this->redirect ()->toRoute ( 'newscategory' );
        }

        $form = new YourForm();
        $form->get ( 'link_id' )->setAttribute ( 'value', $id );
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            // Make certain to merge the files info!
            $image = new Entityimage();
            $form->setInputFilter($image->getInputFilter());
            $post = array_merge_recursive(
                    $request->getPost()->toArray(),
                    $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            );

            $form->setData($post);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $size = new \Zend\Validator\File\ImageSize(array(
                        'minWidth' => 30, 'minHeight' => 30,
                        'maxWidth' => 1024, 'maxHeight' => 920,
                )); //minimum bytes filesize
                $isImage = new \Zend\Validator\File\IsImage();
                $mimeType = new \Zend\Validator\File\MimeType(array('image/gif', 'image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png','enableHeaderCheck' => true));
                $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $post['fileupload']['name']);
                $adapter->setValidators(array($isImage), $post['fileupload']['name']);
                $adapter->setValidators(array($mimeType), $post['fileupload']['name']);

                if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                    $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                    $error = array();
                    foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                    {
                        $error[] = $row;
                    }
                    $form->setMessages(array('fileupload'=>$error ));
                    $messages = $form->getMessages();

                    return $this->redirect ()->toRoute ( 'your route' );
                    // print_r($messages);die('file errors');

                } else {


                    $adapter->setDestination('images/yourdir');

                    if ($adapter->receive($post['fileupload']['name'])) {

                        $image->exchangeArray($form->getData());

                        switch(strtolower($_FILES['fileupload']['type']))
                        {
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                                $filename = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/yourdir/'.$post['fileupload']['name']);
                                break;
                            case 'image/png':
                                $filename = imagecreatefrompng('images/yourdir/'.$post['fileupload']['name']);
                                break;
                            case 'image/gif':
                                $filename = imagecreatefromgif('images/yourdir/'.$post['fileupload']['name']);
                                break;
                            default:
                                exit('Unsupported type: '.$_FILES['fileupload']['type']);
                        }

                        ob_start();
                        imagejpeg($filename);
                        // large image
                        $large = base64_encode(ob_get_contents()); // returns output

                        $mainimgWidth  = imagesx($filename);
                        $mainimgHeight = imagesy($filename);

                        $thumbWidth =   48;                        //intval($mainimgWidth / 4);
                        $thumbHeight =   floor( $mainimgHeight * ( $thumbWidth / $mainimgWidth  ) );   //intval($mainimgHeight / 4);


                        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
                        $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($new, 255, 255, 255);
                        imagefill($new, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
                        imagecopyresampled($new, $filename, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $mainimgWidth, $mainimgHeight);

                        /** Catch the imagedata */
                        ob_start();

                        imagejpeg($new);

                        $data = ob_get_clean();

                        // Destroy resources
                        imagedestroy($filename);
                        imagedestroy($new);

                        // Set new content-type and status code
                        $thumb = base64_encode($data);
                        // imagine library was intsalled by the composer in the test server by amarjit

                        ob_end_clean();

                        $imagine = new Imagine();
                        //rename files
                        $filedata = array(
                                'id'        => $post ['id'],
                                'news_link_id'   => $post ['news_link_id'],
                                'alt'       => $post ['alt'],
                                'detail'    => $post ['detail'],
                                'active'    => $post ['active'],
                                'thumb'     => $thumb,
                                'large'     => $large,
                                'created'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                'createdby'   => 1,
                        );

                        $id =  $this->getImageTable ()->save ( $filedata );
                        $imagine->open('images/yourdir/'.$post['fileupload']['name'])
                        ->save('images/yourdir/filename-'.$id.'.jpg');
                        /**
                         * delete the origional uploaded file;
                        */
                        unlink('images/yourdir/'.$post['fileupload']['name']);
                        return $this->redirect ()->toRoute ( 'newscategory' );

                    }
                }
            }else{
                $messages = $form->getMessages();

            }
        }

        return array (

                'id' => $id,
                'form' => $form,

        );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, however ZF2 has internal solutions that should work themselves. There's too much business logic going on in your controller (though it'd be a last resort for me as well...).