# Rename uploading file in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
   $request = $this->getRequest();
        if($request->isPost()) { 
     $files =  $request->getFiles()->toArray();
     $httpadapter = new Http(); 
     $filesize  = new Size(array('max' => 100000 )); //100KB  
     $extension = new Extension(array('extension' => array('doc')));
     $httpadapter->setValidators(array($filesize, $extension), $files['resume']['name']);
     if($httpadapter->isValid()) {
         $httpadapter->setDestination('./data/upload/');
         if($httpadapter->receive($files['resume']['name'])) {
             $newfile = $httpadapter->getFileName(); 
         }
     }
}
```

Can you tell me how to change the file name before uploading

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953525/zf2-fileupload-collection/23954073#23954073

Comment: can you tell some simple example

Comment: Obviously, by the time the 'php' script gets the files then you have to work with what you are given as regards 'user supplied file names'. However you do not have to use them, as supplied, to name the uploaded files. You do have to link the uploaded files to the name supplied though. There are many ways to do this. Encode the supplied filename as base64 encoding and use that as the filename (with the user id) and make a database entry with that as the key. Note: base64 encoding is **always** safe to use

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this before calling receive method :

```
$destination = './uploads/picture';
$ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newName = md5(rand(). $file['name']) . '.' . $ext;
$adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array(
     'target' => $destination . '/' . $newName,
));
if ($adapter->receive($info['name'])) {
    $file = $adapter->getFilter('File\Rename')->getFile();
    $target = $file[0]['target'];
    var_dump($target);
}
```

Hope it helps